# Download torrent with Dart

Tags: dart

I've searched everywhere for how to download the link a torrent file is pointing to but I can't seem to find anything. The closest [package](https://pub.dev/packages/torrent_streamer) I thought could help me only supports the android platform and I'm targeting macos. Currently I'm using the [webfeed](https://pub.dev/packages/webfeed/example) package to get the rss of torrents but I only have access to the torrent file itself for download. I want to download what it's pointing to. I also have the infohash but I don't know how useful that is. Is there anything I can do to the torrent file such that I can get a direct download link or something?